# How to encrypt a stringbuilder message using AES algorithm in java

Tags: java

I have a stringBuilder message appended with "||" symbol.(Ex: Hi||How||are||26 04 2016||finish)  i have to encrypt the message and send it to the server using AES and decrypt the same at the server side. Can anyone help me out in solving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt and decrypt like this:

```
public class AES {
    public static byte[] encrypt(String key, String initVector, String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec vector = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, vector);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            System.out.println("encrypted string: "+  Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));

            return Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String key, String initVector, byte[] encrypted) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec vector = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, vector);

            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

            return new String(original);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "Foo12345Bar67890"; // 128 bit key
        String initVector = "RandomInitVector"; // 16 bytes IV
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hi||How||are||26 04 2016||finish"); //Your Text here
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encrypt(key, initVector, sb.toString());
        System.out.println(decrypt(key, initVector,encryptedBytes));
    }
}
```